# Java - Função When().ThenReturn() do Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

```
@Mock
RequestUtils requestUtils;
    @Before
    public void init() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        HtmlPage paginaPesquisa = requestUtils.executarPOST(anyObject(),anyObject());
        when(paginaPesquisa).thenReturn(this.getPaginaEstatica(URL_PESQUISA, PAGINA_RESULTADOS_PESQUISA_NOME, "ISO-8859-1" ));
        when(requestUtils.getPaginaResultados(anyObject())).thenReturn(this.getPaginaEstatica(URL_PESQUISA,PAGINA_RESULTADOS_PESQUISA_IDADE, "ISO-8859-1"));
        when(paginaPesquisa.getWebClient().getPage(anyObject().toString())).thenReturn(this.getPaginaEstatica(URL_PAGINA_INICIAL,PAGINA_INICIAL,"ISO-8859-1"));
    }
```

O problema é que neste ultimo when:

```
when(paginaPesquisa.getWebClient().getPage(anyObject().toString()))
```

Dá um `NullPointerException` até porque nem tem como recuperar o `webClient`.

Procurei funções do Mockito, para este caso mas não achei nada... O que fazer?

Comment: **Acho** que você precisa colocar um `thenReturn(paginaPesquisa.getWebClient())` antes desse `when`.

Comment: como assim? tentei e não deu certo.

Comment: Escrevi errado. A ideia era essa: `when(paginaPesquisa.getWebClient()).thenReturn(valorMockado)`

Comment: Já tentei, mas a paginaPesquisa já esta mocada antes, então dá um NullPointerException no when()...